# Using Swing toolkit to build Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, animation

I'm about to start a project where I will be building a road network simulator. The program will in terms of the GUI, be in 2D so basically a top down view of roads with simple moving cars etc.

I do have some experience with Swing , and I've used it to build a simulator before but not in  the sense of providing an actual animation of moving objects etc. Hence, my question is, do you recommend using swing for such a project, or is there other possibilities which will be more suited for this type of application? I don't know too much about other toolkits, but the main reason I ask is to make sure that swing does not limit me in any way from what I need to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using Swing for this purpose.  There are a number of excellent open source animation API's that will make you're life a lot easier.

- [TimingFramework](http://java.net/projects/timingframework)
- [Trident](http://kenai.com/projects/trident/pages/Home)

You'll have evaluate each of these yourself to see which will meet your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent links. I have reached the conclusion to use Swing throughout the project. With the aid of animation APIs such as the ones proposed above shouldn't put a limit to what I intend to do. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend javafx because oracle will support it.Swing is dead oracle won't make new bug fixes and they will no create more features

Comment: A link to the said thingy might be more helpful to provide more information regarding [JavaFX 2](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/overview/jfxpub-overview.htm). +1 though, for the suggestion, did that already 5 mins back :-)

Comment: No offense, but where is that written?  Sure, I agree, it's been awhile between updates, but that hardly says it's a dead API. Not to say your suggestion is invalid, but I would question the validity of the clam, IHMO

Comment: -1 there is no way that you can say "Swing is dead". It is still fully supported as part of the core Java runtime shipped by Oracle and is the standard approach to building cross-platform GUIs in Java. JavaFX and Swing will continue co-exist because they target somewhat different use cases.